# Getting multiple images in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, http, servlets, spring-data-jpa

I want a method to get multiple images with just one request, which I can later display on html using javascript.

I have already implemented this method in my Controller class which returns me a single image.

```
@GetMapping(value = "/images/{imageName}", produces = MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG_VALUE)
    public void serveFile(@PathVariable("imageName") String imageName, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {

        InputStream resource =  this.pageService.getResource(path, imageName);
        response.setContentType(MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG_VALUE);
        StreamUtils.copy(resource, response.getOutputStream());
    }
```

Now I have a database with the tables "Book" and "Page". In the table "page" the file names of the images are stored as varchar and the IDs of the books are stored as foreign keys. For example, I want to output all pages, i.e. the image files, with the book ID 50

I tried to implement the following methods in my Controller and Service class but I get this Exception:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to class java.io.InputStream

```
//controller
@GetMapping("images/bookid/{bookid}")
    public void getPages(@PathVariable("bookid") Long bookid, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {

        List<InputStream> resources = pageService.getAllResources(bookid);
        response.setContentType(MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG_VALUE);
        StreamUtils.copy((InputStream) resources, response.getOutputStream());

    }
```

```
//service
public List<InputStream> getAllResources(Long id) throws FileNotFoundException {

        List<String> imagepaths = pageRepo.findImagePathByBookID(id);
        List<InputStream> inputStreamList = new ArrayList<>();

        for (String imagePath : imagepaths){
            inputStreamList.add(new FileInputStream(this.path + File.separator + imagePath));
        }

        return inputStreamList;
    }
```

Is it even possible to return a list of images?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to return a byte array containing several images.

1. You need to pack all images in a single byte array, and add a unique sequence of bytes (separator) between the images so that you can split the byte array into several images on the client side.
2. On the client side you read byte by byte and search for a separator. If found, you form an image from the already read bytes.

Some thoughts on the solution:

Even if that's technically not complex to implement, you should reconsider the architecture of your application. This approach is viable in rear cases then you have to precisely control the transferring of every single byte.

Comment: It might be better to include the length if the images before them instead of using a sequence for distinction. A defined sequence could randomly occur in the image.